# How can the build status be changed using Jacoco with Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jacoco

Using Jenkins Jacoco Plugin version 3.0.1 with the following configuration generates a valid coverage report but fails to actually change the build status.

```
                jacoco( 
                    execPattern: '**/target/code-coverage/**.exec',
                    classPattern: '**/target/classes',
                    sourcePattern: '**/src',
                    inclusionPattern: 'com/company/**',
                    changeBuildStatus: true,
                    minimumInstructionCoverage: '70'
                )
```

The logged output is

```
[JaCoCo plugin] Overall coverage: class: 19, method: 9, line: 4, branch: 2, instruction: 3
[JaCoCo plugin] Health thresholds: JacocoHealthReportThresholds [minClass=0, maxClass=0, minMethod=0, maxMethod=0, minLine=0, maxLine=0, minBranch=0, maxBranch=0, minInstruction=0, maxInstruction=0, minComplexity=0, maxComplexity=0]
[JaCoCo plugin] Apply Min/Max thresholds result: SUCCESS
```

The "Apply Min/Max thresholds" line indicates that the changeBuildStatus flag was registered, but the threshold value all show as 0.

Does changeBuildStatus actually work with pipeline, and if so what is the correct format for setting thresholds?

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: It is version 3.0.1

Comment: Thats in the first line of your question, My bad!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, I needed to add a corresponding maximumCoverage value. For example,

```
jacoco(
    execPattern: '**/target/code-coverage/**.exec',
    classPattern: '**/target/classes',
    sourcePattern: '**/src',
    inclusionPattern: 'com/company/**',
    changeBuildStatus: true,
    minimumInstructionCoverage: '70',
    maximumInstructionCoverage: '80'
)
```

Hope this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For more JaCoCo plugin fields... https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jacoco/ has a list of accepted parameters.